# Codeigniter Delete using Javascript Ajax Can not Return to status

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to delete multiple with checkbox

successfully delete the data.. but can't remove in list
i must refresh twice to delete data ..

this is code

```
 // link for click
 <a href="" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-xs" onclick="delete();">Delete</a>

 //checkbox
 <input type="checkbox" name="id" class="data-check" id="am" value="<?php echo $row->MenuId;?>">


        //function to call 
              function delete()
              {
                  var list_id = [];
                  $(".data-check:checked").each(function() {
                          list_id.push(this.value);
                  });
                  if(list_id.length > 0)
                  {
                      if(confirm('Are you sure delete this '+list_id.length+' data?'))
                      {
                          $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              data: {id:list_id},
                              url: "<?php echo site_url('General_setting/delete_multiple')?>",
                              dataType: "JSON",
                              success: function(data)
                              {
                                if(data){
                                  window.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('General_setting'); ?>';
                                }
                              }
                          });
                      //return false;
                      }
                    }

                  else
                  {
                      alert('no data selected');
                  }
              }

//controller

    function delete_multiple() {
        $this->load->model('Menu_model');
        $data=$this->Menu_model->remove_menu();
        if($data){
            return true;
        }
    }



    //// model
    function remove_menu() {

            $delete = $this->input->post('id');
            for ($i=0; $i < count($delete) ; $i++) { 
                $this->db->where('MenuId', $delete[$i]);
                $this->db->delete('Menu');
            }

        return false;
    }
```

I dont know ho to return .. to succes or failed
I think i have a mistake .. but i dont know what .. can you tell me where the mistake ..
Thank you ..

Comment: use redirect('controller/method', 'refresh');

Comment: in controller ? or view ? or model ?

Comment: i was change evrything in my code .. and its done.. finally i didn't use ajax